Plugin.BLE returning NULL services .NET MAUI
I am trying to connect two devices using Plugin.BLE and send data from one device to another.
showDevices.xaml.cs
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Extensions;
using Plugin.BLE.Android;
using SampleData.Services;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleData;

public partial class ShowDevices : ContentPage
{
    private List<string> _devices;
    private IReadOnlyList<IDevice> _systemDevices;
    private IAdapter _adapter;
    public ShowDevices(List<string> devices, IReadOnlyList<IDevice> systemDevices, IAdapter adapter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._devices = devices;
        this._systemDevices = systemDevices;
        this._adapter = adapter;
        lst.ItemsSource = _devices;
    }
    private async void TextCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var device = _systemDevices.First();

        var guid = device.Id;

        try
        {
            _adapter.ConnectToKnownDeviceAsync(guid);

           // await DisplayAlert("Response", $"{guid}", "Ok");

            await DisplayAlert("Connected Established !!!", $"{device.Name}", "Ok");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
        }
    }
        private async void SendData()
        {
            var Device = _systemDevices.FirstOrDefault();
            if (Device != null)
            {
                var guid = Device.Id;
                try
                {
                 await DisplayAlert("Response", "Sending the data, please wait!", "Ok");
                    
                var services = await Device.GetServicesAsync();
                var message = await APIService.GetData();
                var convertedMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

                foreach (var service in services)
                    {
                    var char_guid = Guid.Parse("0x2B2E");
                        var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(char_guid);
                        await DisplayAlert("char", $"{characteristic}", "Ok");
                        if (characteristic != null)
                        {
                            byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(convertedMsg);
                            await characteristic.WriteAsync(msg);
                            await DisplayAlert("Sent!!!", "Message sent successfully", "Ok");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Characteristic not found!", "Couldn't find the specified characteristic", "Ok");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
                }
            }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "No device connected", "Ok");
        }       
        }

    private void sendBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SendData();
    }
}

The device is getting identified properly it is also returning appropriate id, but nothing was being sent, so added a breakpoint and found that the services are return null , in the following line.
 var services = await Device.GetServicesAsync();
I am unable to figure out this issue.
Help appreciated!
